# Is there a scientific basis for the claim that the 3rd day from the circumcision is the most painful and dangerous?

Tags: medicine, brit-milah, science

Is there a scientific basis for the claim that the third day from the day of a circumcision is the most painful and dangerous?

In Mishana (shabbath 19,3)

> מרחיצין את הקטן בין לפני המילה ובין לאחר המילה ומזלפין עליו ביד
>   אבל לא בכלי **ר' אליעזר בן עזריה אומר מרחיצין את הקטן ביום השלישי שחל
>   להיות בשבת שנא' (בראשית לד) ויהי ביום השלישי בהיותם כואבים** ספק
>   ואנדרוגינוס אין מחללין עליו את השבת ורבי יהודה מתיר באנדרוגינוס.

It seems that Rabi Eliezer Ben Azaria allows to do מלאכה in Shabbath based on his understanding that this is the most dangerous day for the baby. Isn't it?

Rambam* allows to wash the baby with warm water in the 1st and 3rd day only (*according to the most of the interpreters, Meiri, Magid Mishne, Ritva, Ran, Bet Yosef, Bakh, and others. See more in Tora Shlema, Bereshith p.1327 which states Eben Ezra and others about the similar opinion)

> מלו את הקטן בשבת ואחר כך נשפכו החמין או נתפזרו הסממנין עושין לו הכל
>   בשבת מפני שסכנה היא לו, מקום שדרכן להרחיץ את הקטן מרחיצין אותו בשבת
>   ביום המילה בין לפני המילה בין לאחר המילה **או בשלישי של מילה שחל להיות
>   בשבת**, בין רחיצת כל גופו, בין רחיצת מילה, בין בחמין שהוחמו מערב שבת בין
>   בחמין שהוחמו בשבת מפני שסכנה היא לו.

Anyway, my question is if this opinion has a scientific basis.

Comment: Already in the days of the Shulchan Arukh ~16th century they no longer considered washing on the third day a significant medical need.

Comment: It's not accurate, since Rama (who was after Shulchan Arukh) says (331,9): "הגה:   **ובמדינות אלו נוהגים לרחצו** לפני המילה בחמין שהוחמו מאתמול, ולאחר המילה במוצאי שבת.

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wound_healing) stages

Comment: @ubiqu they didn't do melakha on shabbat anymore. They changed the circumcision process due to changing science.

Comment: I have a friend who became a convert and he told me the 3rd day was very painful

Comment: Regarding the off-topic votes: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4800/is-fact-checking-judaism-on-topic

Comment: The other question seems primarily focused on the Torah source rather than the medical source. Perhaps we should remove the medical part from the other question since the top answer didn't address it at all and the second answer only slightly addressed it, and allow that to be its own question here rather than closing this one as a duplicate and leaving one post to discuss two separate questions.